# Is there documentation for classes option for Django fieldset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the [Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets), it mentions fieldsets. The example they specify a class `collapse`. This class will make the fieldset collapsible in the admin page. I found 2 other examples of a classes one could use. I found looking for a list of other classes I can use is `wide` or `extrapretty`. Other than these examples I have not been able to find anything else about the `classes` option in the fieldset.

Answer (score 2):

It's now added to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets):

```
collapse, wide
```

But you can use any class you want from form CSS, or write your own.